# How to setup a STATIC IP ADDRESS while using Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, static-ip-address

I have an application running on Google Cloud's App Engine(flexible environment).

An external API that deals with finances requires us to have a static external IP address so that we may interact. I know App Engine doesn't have an external IP address feature.

I'm also aware that using Google Cloud's Compute Engine, a VM instance with a static IP can be set up.

Is there anyone that has run into this situation and figured out an efficient solution?

Comment: Use a compute engine with static ip to act as a proxy for your app engine. Will that work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

As the [FAQ for Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip) says, App engine does not support static IP.

The only workaround is to use a VM with an static ip to be as a proxy. There is a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145648/assigning-static-ip-address-to-gae-python-project?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: Update your link to a specific page with details. Your link goes to a documentation home page.